# Can my R code talk to spark and spark sql

Tags: r, apache-spark

I have a use case where I have revolution R on my desktop and want to invoke/talk to spark and spark sql deployed in a hadoop cluster(also have sparkR installed there).Any suggestions on how to proceed on this.I heard it can be done if spark is in stand alone mode.But I want with sparn in yarn mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the sparkR package. This also helps in connecting to the Spark SQL as you had required

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/sparkr.html

Comment: Thanks karthik..but im trying to connect my rstudio version to spark in yarn mode...can you help me in understanding how this can be achieved ?